# Bluetooth not enable when cold boot. 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

Bluetooth not enable when cold boot. Ubuntu 22.04

Everytime I cold boot, I have to execute this command below

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

But If I restart the system for any reason then it working & no need to execute the command but only when cold boot.

Result of `lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` below

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b424 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[sudo] password for krishna: 
[    0.100406] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x0000000078800000-0x000000007affffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
[    0.100411] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: Your BIOS is broken; bad RMRR [0x0000000078800000-0x000000007affffff]
[    0.185428] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.718809] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    0.718821] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[    3.567764] elan_i2c i2c-ELAN1000:00: Elan Touchpad: Module ID: 0x0005, Firmware: 0x0004, Sample: 0x000d, IAP: 0x000a
[    3.679892] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.ca7b901d.0 8000C-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.352305] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
[    4.518822] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.518841] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.518842] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.518846] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.518847] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.518851] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.655248] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[    4.660283] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[    4.660285] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    4.660287] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    4.660288] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    4.660289] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    4.660290] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    4.663460] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[    4.757347] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.757351] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.757355] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.757347] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38)
[    5.757374] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel reset sent to retry FW download
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` after a cold boot but before executing your commands

Comment: @Jeremy31 thanks. I updated it.

Comment: Try in terminal `echo "options btusb enable_autosuspend=n" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/btusb.conf` Then reboot

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31 that did not work

Comment: No more ideas, other than you could blacklist btusb and then all you you would have to after boot is sudo modprobe btusb

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue recently. I solved it by disabling *Fast boot* on my system's BIOS.

Comment: `Fast Boot` and `Secure Boot` both are disabled in my system.